# du -h returns 512, what does it mean?

Tags: du

I have some files for which `du -h` returns `512`, my understanding it is supposed to return numbers with units. What does it mean ? What is the actual disk space being used ?

good file

```
(base) -bash-4.2$ du -h 2020.110/drr0/X1.0060_0958
36K 2020.110/drr0/X1.0060_0958
(base) -bash-4.2$ ls -l 2020.110/drr0/X1.0060_0958
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user11 users 36628 Jul 29 18:43 2020.110/drr0/X1.0060_0958
```

bad file

```
(base) -bash-4.2$ du -h 2020.110/drr0/X1.0060_0957
512 2020.110/drr0/X1.0060_0957
(base) -bash-4.2$ ls -l 2020.110/drr0/X1.0060_0957
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user11 users 0 Jul 29 18:51 2020.110/drr0/X1.0060_0957
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

du never shows units. Notice that **in both cases** there is no 'B' (for bytes) in the output – the "human-readable" mode only shows *multiplier prefixes* (K, M, G) but not units themselves. And as there is no prefix for numbers below 1024, none is shown.

Normally 'du' measures files in blocks (see manual page), but with the '-h' option, the unit is always 1 byte. So when `du -h` shows `512`, that's 512 bytes.

Why 512 and not 0? See phuclv's answer

Comment: Small clarification here, du -h does show units whenever a file is more than 1024 bytes. So it represents bytes as a number, but kB, mB, gB, and so on have units.

Comment: @anonymous: "36KB" would have a unit (bytes), but "36K" does not – "kilo" is not a unit by itself. 36K is just 36 kilo*something*. (Or 36 kelvins but that's clearly not applicable here.)

Comment: Ah, my brain assumed that it said kB. On closer inspection, it says K.

Answer (score 7):

Files aren't always consuming space on disk. Files with fewer data blocks than the real size will be reported with a smaller number of blocks

- [Sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) will only have non-zero blocks stored on disk. So a 50TB sparse file with only 5MB non-zero data will consume only ~5MB on disk
- [Inline files](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data) will also consume 0 byte in the data area, because they're stored right in the metadata itself. In NTFS it's called [resident files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Resident_vs._non-resident_attributes) and later many other Linux file systems like ext4 or [Btrfs](https://linux-btrfs.vger.kernel.narkive.com/D0gCQEcr/why-btrfs-inline-small-file-by-default) also support a similar feature
- [Compressed files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(data_compression)) also have a smaller number of blocks after compressing

Probably your file is inlined. Since it has no allocated blocks, the number reported by `ls` will be 0. You can easily check that with `stat`. In ext4 only files very small compared to the inode size (256+ bytes) can be inlined, so probably you're using another file system like NTFS or Btrfs

You can use the `--apparent-size` option in `du` to see the real size

> `--apparent-size`
>
> print apparent sizes, rather than disk usage; although the apparent size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes in ('sparse') files, internal fragmentation, indirect blocks, and the like
>
> https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html